# Tabulação no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Olá 
Tenho uma planilha com alguns dados sobre importações da receita federal. Sobre essa planilha eu faço uma tabulação de dados, baseado em uma das colunas que vem nessa planilha chamada de "descrição do produto", dessa coluna eu verifico as informações e juntamente com um historico que possuo de tabulacões anteriores, consigo dizer quem produz, importa, quantidade e etc.
Gostaria de automatizar  esse processo baseado no campo da descrição e comparando com meu historico.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Amigo, ajuda se vc der mais detalhes, fornecer um recorte dos seus dados tabulados e da sua planilha de análise. O que exatamente vc analisa na coluna de "Descrição do Produto"? Que informação vc extrai dali para chegar a conclusão de quais são as demais inforamções? Por favor, esclareça melhor seu problema e forneça mais informações e terei o maior prazer em te ajudar!

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, assim que possivel explico mais detalhadamente ok. Agradeço a disposição em ajudar.